# Mac not detecting Logitech receiver on Unifying Software

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mouse

I am using Logitech wireless keyboard K270 and mouse M185 with my MacBook Air (currently OSX 10.10.5) for more than a year now. All of a sudden today after some time, my keyboard and mouse stopped working. I checked the batteries all seems to be OK. I connected the Unifying receiver again after restart with Logitech Unifying Software and got this message.

[image]

Has anyone faced this problem before, do I need to reinstall the Logitech Unifying Software again? I also can't even get download this software anywhere on the internet, there are only Windows versions. Not sure what to do :-(

Update: In the System reports I can see the following entries
[image]

Comment: Kinda sounds like the USB receiver died :( - check that the OS can see it from  > About this Mac > System Report > USB

Comment: What am I expected to see there? I have added the snapshot in the updated question.

Comment: alt/click the reveal triangles to show the connected devices - one of them should be your Unifying Key

Comment: Can't see any unifying key thr, I have update the snapshot.

Comment: Yup, could be the thing has died. Double-check the USB socket itself with any other device & make sure it appears in that list [might need to close/open the window again to refresh

Comment: I have the same issue, but I can see it in the System Report. What should I do then?

Comment: I have a mouse and keyboard combo. But my mouse is connected but keyboard is not getting connected. When I installed Logitech Unified Softwares it is giving the same issue. There is no unifying receiver plugged into your computer.

Answer (score 2):

The system information is showing that the hardware is not being detected. The drivers are probably fine but idle since they don’t see the USB hardware for Logitech.

You can confirm this by removing logitech, then plugging in another usb mouse or something and refreshing the System Information. You should see that device be listed and know your Mac and USB are fine.

Once you’re sure the Logitech dongle is not working, here is a DIY repair you could try if you can’t get a repair / replacement part:

The fix is to remove the black cover, slide out the PCB, insert a piece of paper that raises the metal connectors of the chip closer to your laptop's USB connector. Reassemble everything. Once the chip and the USB port are properly touching again you will see the receiver show up in the Mac Systems USB panel and in Logitech Control Center, as others pointed out. You can also look for a visual tutorial of this on youtube / google.

As these age, this is, sadly, a widespread problem with the Logitech receiver.

Comment: Youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NlYRsVJB74

Answer (score 0):

I use: Logitech G305 / macOS Big Sur (V. 11.6.1) / MacBook Air (M1, 2020)
I managed to solve the problem. My problem was that when I connected the mouse "Logitech G305” it worked, but the Logitech program did not see the device. I always received the following message: no devices detected.
The solution is to only use the app - Logitech G Hub. Logitech no longer deals with other applications:

- Firmware Update Tool;
- Logitech Gaming Software;
- Logi Option.

It took me almost all day. I haven't found information anywhere, not even on the official product website Logitech G305.

https://thegamingsetup.com/gaming-mouse/buying-guides/logitech-gaming-software-g-hub

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my receiver died. Luckily I had an extra so I used logitech's [Connect-your-device-to-a-Logitech-USB-receiver](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023193454-Connect-your-device-to-a-Logitech-USB-receiver) to attach the new receiver to my mouse. Once I did that I was able to connect the mouse to my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd offer this solution for newer (post-2020) versions of macOS.

It didn't work for me until I enabled `Input Monitoring` for the Logitech Unifying Software.

Open System Settings and go to "Privacy & Security" (or type "input monitoring" in the settings search bar.

[image: macOS-System-Settings-Input-Monitoring]

Then just enable "Input Monitoring" for the Logitech software by toggling the  switch button "on"

[image: Enable input monitoring for Logitech Unifying Software in macOS]

Once enabled, just restart the Logitech software and it should detect the USB receiver now.

Comment: This was the most logical solution. unfortunately didn't work :(

Comment: Yes, this solution no longer works for me either. In fact, I had to use the Linux package to finally get the Logitech software to even detect the dongle, let alone pair it with a new device--even the Windows version did not work for me.